# Replace Timestamp in Written Text File

Tags: java, datetime

I need to read a file and write it in a new file, the file that I read has it own time stamp, but in the written file I need to replace it with the current time eg( 2020-09-20 19:30 change it to 2020-09-30 01:30) I have been able to read and write it using the following code, but I am struggling with the change time stamp part

```
            FileInputStream inputRead = null;
            FileOutputStream outWrite = null;
        
            try{
                  
                File infile =new File("test.txt");
                File outfile =new File("test_log.txt");
     
                inputRead = new FileInputStream(infile);
                outWrite = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
     
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
     
                int length;             
                while ((length = inputRead.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    
                    System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    
                    outWrite.write(buffer, 0, length);
                    
                    
                
            }

               
                inputRead.close();
                outWrite.close();
     
            
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
         }
        }
```

Sorry forgot to mention the Line Read is as follows " 20-09-2020 19:30 (Some Parameter) " to "(current date) + (Some Parameter)

Comment: Umm,  I don't understand. Do you want to change it to 12 hr timestamp from 24 hour notation? What's the required logic for changing timestamp?

Comment: I wish to change the timestamp from the file that was read to a current time in the new written text

Comment: ohk, Sorry. Looks like I misunderstood your problem. You can take a look at answers from other contributors using search and replace approach. I think they are helpful

Comment: Its okay, Thanks I will look at the other answers as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    File infile = new File("test.txt");
    File outfile = new File("test_log.txt");
    DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    try (
            BufferedReader inputRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(infile)));
            BufferedWriter outWrite = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outfile)))
    ) {
        String line;
        while ((line = inputRead.readLine()) != null) {
            outWrite.write(System.lineSeparator());
            String modifiedString = line.replaceAll("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}", dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
            outWrite.write(modifiedString);
        }
    }
```

Expanding my answer a bit for clarity.
I've added try-with-resources, you don't need to close the streams manually which should otherwise be done in a finally (if it crashes they are left open).
I've added readers which is a higher level api on top of the stream. for convenience.
I've added search and replace on the string using regex that matches your example string. In my example above i'm using strings which could probably be optimized if needed.

Comment: Hi I tried to use your coding, but somehow it did not replace the date. is it also possible to pnly replace a partial part of the string? for example " 2020-10-30 08:30 Extra Word" to "2020-10-31 11:30 Extra Word"?

Comment: If it did not replace the format you have given differs from what you have. The regex is looking for 4digits-2digits-2digits 2digits:2digits. If you want to add a word then 2 capturing groups needs to be added where thi first is replaced and second is kept

Comment: I see, yeah the format differs, haha but sorry I dont understand this part "If you want to add a word then 2 capturing groups needs to be added where thi first is replaced and second is kept" hope you can explain it further.

Comment: have a look at this https://regex101.com/r/4X0Abk/1 and look on the right side. there you will see the capturing groups where you can see the groups

Comment: Hi, I try to use the code you provided, even change the format of the date, but it still could not change the date to the current date

Comment: @ABAB you need to give an example/sample of your actual string if we are going to be able to help you. the code is very simple and works so its clear that the data is different...

Comment: oops sorry my bad the code does work, I forgot to adjust the time format, since it searches for 2 digit, while in the sample string was only a single digit. my vbad and thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
String nextTimeStamp = "2020-09-30 01:30";
Path infile = Paths.get("test.txt");
Path outfile = Paths.get("test_log.txt");
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(infile, Charset.defaultCharset());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outfile.toFile()) {
    lines.map(line -> line.replaceAll("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}", nextTimeStamp)
        .forEach(line -> out.println(line));
}
```

(For a fixed Charset add an extra parameter with this Charset to PrintWriter too.

Java `String` is for *text*, `byte[]` for binary data. And on String one can do replace and other text operations.

`line.replaceAll` uses a regular expression to match. If you have the exact string to be replaced, you can use `line.replace`.

The syntax of what is called try-with-resources accepts AutoCloseable's inside `try (...)` and will ensure the objects are closed even on exception or return/break.

Comment: Hi, thank you but what if I only to replace only part of the string? for example "2020-09-20 19:30 Extra Word" to "2020-09-30 01:30 Extra Word"?

Comment: I do not understand, `"foobarfoobarfoo",replaceAll("bar", "BAZ")` would give `"fooBAZfooBAZfoo"`.

Comment: I try to use the code you provided but at the line        `.forEach(line -> out.println(line);`
        `    }` give me an error of `Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
  QualifiedName
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
 - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
  MethodHeaderName
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
  SingleMemberAnnotation`

Comment: It had to be )). Corrected